# Swift How to wrap long text of label in collection cell and set margin in text label

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

For now, I am using custom collection view layout to implement this.

[image]

Each cell contains a label with different length of text. I return the width of cell by using the function below:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, widthForSubsectionAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let text = subsections[indexPath.row]
    let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica neue", size: 24)
    dLog("height ==> \(height)")
    let rect = NSString(string: text).boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT), height: height), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font!], context: nil)
    dLog("rect ==> \(rect)")
    return rect.width
}
```

This can wrap text just as shown in picture. But I also want to make the distance between text is the same. The red circles above are not in same size. I guess it depends on the length of text.

Here is the constrain that I am using:
[image]

How can I set margin distance between text and cell same and at same time wrap words correctly?

BTW, When I output the `height` and `rect` information in console, I find the height information is different. The height of grey bar is actually 50. Here is the output:

> [SubsectionHeaderCollectionViewController.swift:91] collectionView(*:widthForSubsectionAtIndexPath:height:) - height ==> 50.0
>   2016-06-24 12:13:50.507 Atlas[12714:496386] [SubsectionHeaderCollectionViewController.swift:93] collectionView(*:widthForSubsectionAtIndexPath:height:) - rect ==> (0.0, 0.0, 63.192, 27.96)
>   2016-06-24 12:13:50.507 Atlas[12714:496386] [SubsectionHeaderCollectionViewController.swift:91] collectionView(*:widthForSubsectionAtIndexPath:height:) - height ==> 50.0
>   2016-06-24 12:13:50.507 Atlas[12714:496386] [SubsectionHeaderCollectionViewController.swift:93] collectionView(*:widthForSubsectionAtIndexPath:height:) - rect ==> (0.0, 0.0, 60.432, 27.96)
>   2016-06-24 12:13:50.507 Atlas[12714:496386] [SubsectionHeaderCollectionViewController.swift:91] collectionView(*:widthForSubsectionAtIndexPath:height:) - height ==> 50.0
>   2016-06-24 12:13:50.508 Atlas[12714:496386] [SubsectionHeaderCollectionViewController.swift:93] collectionView(*:widthForSubsectionAtIndexPath:height:) - rect ==> (0.0, 0.0, 241.8, 27.96)
>   2016-06-24 12:13:50.508 Atlas[12714:496386] [SubsectionHeaderCollectionViewController.swift:91] collectionView(*:widthForSubsectionAtIndexPath:height:) - height ==> 50.0
>   2016-06-24 12:13:50.508 Atlas[12714:496386] [SubsectionHeaderCollectionViewController.swift:93] collectionView(*:widthForSubsectionAtIndexPath:height:) - rect ==> (0.0, 0.0, 98.232, 27.96)
>   2016-06-24 12:13:50.508 Atlas[12714:496386] [SubsectionHeaderCollectionViewController.swift:91] collectionView(*:widthForSubsectionAtIndexPath:height:) - height ==> 50.0
>   2016-06-24 12:13:50.508 Atlas[12714:496386] [SubsectionHeaderCollectionViewController.swift:93] collectionView(*:widthForSubsectionAtIndexPath:height:) - rect ==> (0.0, 0.0, 56.88, 27.96)

Comment: are you want to set label width according to it's text?

Comment: Yes, but the spacing between text should be identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove  equal width ,equal height constraints and add label leading and trailing space to cell  say (constan  10), and also set constraint equal height to the cell height, after that  dynamically set width of the cell based of the text in the label. add this  function cell.layoutIfNeeded() in cellForIndexMethod after set width.

Answer (score 0):

plz set the width constraints grater Than or equal[image]

here this label width set accroding to its text. hope its help

Answer (score 0):

Inside your custom collectionView cell object, set your label's numberOfLines property to zero.

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

then in your constraints, pin your label on the leading and trailing edges of the custom collectionView cells.

```
yourLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
yourLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
```